# Is it possible to serve different index.html for desktop and mobile websites with spring boot mobile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-mobile

I have a React Single Page APP (SPA) that I want to serve both mobile and desktop users with. Trouble is that I have two different versions of my app for desktop or mobile because the home page UI differs by quite a bit between desktop or mobile.

Using Spring Boot mobile to distinguish which device a user is visiting my app from, is it possible to serve different index.html?

So say, for a mobile visitor I'd want to serve my indexMobile.html and for a desktop user I'd serve indexDesktop.html as the home page, can you do this with Spring Boot?

So far, all the online guides I've seen eventually boil down to using either different Thymeleaf  templates (which I'm not using, I'm using react app) or simply using a single index.html as  the entry point into the app but I need different home page entrypoints in my app.

Help any one?

Answer (score 0):

I think css [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) may help

Or you may use css framework([Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/),
[W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp)) to reduce designing time